# Table of Contents and Title Page

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, page-numbering

On the PDF version of my file, when I click on the first entry of the TOC, it leads to the title page. How to fix that?

Here is my title page:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{titlepage}
    \hspace{-1.5cm}
    
    \centering
    \vspace{1cm}
    {\LARGE\noindent \textbf{TITLE OF MY WORK} \par}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    %Thesis subtitle
    {\Large\noindent \par}
    \vspace{2cm}
 \vspace{1cm}
{\Large
by}

\vspace{1cm}
    
    {\LARGE\noindent  MY NAME \par} 
    \vspace{1cm}
{\Large \noindent Submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of Master of Applied Science \par
\vspace{1cm}   
April 2023} 
    \vfill  
    \hrule
    \vspace{0.3cm}

{\Large\noindent \textcopyright Copyright by .....} 
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage
```

And here is the code for the first entry of my toc (list of tables):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%TABLE OF CONTENTS
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\tableofcontents 
\addtocontents{toc}{\textbf{\contentsname}\dotfill\thepage\par}
\cleardoublepage


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% LIST OF TABLES
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\cleardoublepage

\thispagestyle{plain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}{\pagestyle{plain}}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setlength{\cftparskip}{1.5\baselineskip}
\listoftables

\cleardoublepage
```

Comment: Without compiling code, I would, e.g, suggest to add `\pagenumbering{Roman}` before `\begin{titlepage}`. BTW: `\setcounter{page}{1}` after `\pagenumbering{…}` is not needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDF page labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246705/pdf-page-labels)

Comment: Not actually... it is still leading to the cover page...

Comment: your code is incomplete and can't be tested. But basically you have to ensure that every page as an unique pagenumber (where roman i is different to arabic 1). Try \pagenumbering{Roman} on the titlepage so that it has not an arabic number that you use later too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `\phantomsection` before `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}` to make the link point to the List of Tables page.

Try this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftparskip}{1.5\baselineskip}

\usepackage{hyperref} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
}

\begin{document}        
    
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \centering
        \vspace{1cm}
        {\LARGE\noindent \textbf{TITLE OF MY WORK} \par}
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        %Thesis subtitle
        {\Large\noindent \par}
        \vspace{2cm}
        \vspace{1cm}
        {\Large
            by}
        
        \vspace{1cm}
        
        {\LARGE\noindent  MY NAME \par} 
        \vspace{1cm}
        {\Large \noindent Submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of Master of Applied Science \par
            \vspace{1cm}   
            April 2023} 
        \vfill  
        \hrule
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        
        {\Large\noindent \textcopyright\ Copyright by .....} 
    \end{titlepage}
    \cleardoublepage
    
    \pagenumbering{roman} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
    \tableofcontents
    \cleardoublepage    

    \phantomsection % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
    \listoftables   
    \cleardoublepage        

    \pagenumbering{arabic} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \chapter{One}
    
    Some text.
    
    \begin{table}[ht!]      
        \caption{Artic Shipping Routes.}
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{table}[ht!]      
        \caption{Unique ships entering the Polar Code area 2013 and 2019. Source: adapted from PAME (2020)}
    \end{table}
    
    \chapter{Two}
    
    Some more text.
    
    \begin{table}[ht!]          
            \caption{Sea Ice Extent.}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[ht!]          
        \caption{Canadian Artic Classes and Ice type related to each of them. Source: Transport Canada (2017)}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[ht!]          
        \caption{Shipping Safety Control Zones.}
    \end{table}

    \chapter{Three}

    Some text.
    
    \begin{table}[ht!]          
        \caption{Artic Shipping Routes.}
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{table}[ht!]      
        \caption{Unique ships entering the Polar Code area 2013 and 2019. Source: adapted from PAME (2020)}
    \end{table}
    
    \chapter{Four}
    
    Some more text.
    
    \begin{table}[ht!]  
        \caption{Sea Ice Extent.}
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{table}[ht!]  
        \caption{Canadian Artic Classes and Ice type related to each of them. Source: Transport Canada (2017)}
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{table}[ht!]      
        \caption{Shipping Safety Control Zones.}
    \end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image: bx]

Comment: That worked, Simon! Thank you!