# Why do I have this big space in the list of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, lists

I want to understand why I have this huge space in my list of figures, after the title?

[image]

My code is this one:

```
\chapter*{List of Figures}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}{\pagestyle{plain}}
\setlength{\cftparskip}{1.5\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{}

\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried `\raggedbottom` instead of `\flushbottom` ?

Comment: I‘m afraid in most cases such a code snippet won‘t be enough to point you into the right direction … Simple test: a) does it compile? b) if so, does it show your problem?

Comment: Do please reveal which document class you employ.

Comment: Hi, the document class is report. Where would I add \raggedbottom or \fushbottom?

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the space between the chapter title and its content twice: the first time when you create an unnumbered chapter (    `\chapter*{List of Figures}`) and the second time when `\listoffigures` (itself a chapter) is issued with a blank name (`\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{}`}.

The standard style for the first page of a chapter (for report or book) is plain, so `\thispagestyle{plain}` is not necessary.

Please try this minimum code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftparskip}{1.5\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    \cleardoublepage    

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
    \listoffigures      
    \cleardoublepage        

    \chapter{One}
    
    Some text.
    
    \begin{figure}  
        \includegraphics{example-image-a}
        \caption{Artic Shipping Routes.}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}  
        \includegraphics{example-image-a}
        \caption{Unique ships entering the Polar Code area 2013 and 2019. Source: adapted from PAME (2020)}
    \end{figure}
    
    \chapter{Two}
    
    Some more text.
    
    \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics{example-image-b}
            \caption{Sea Ice Extent.}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{example-image-b}
        \caption{Canadian Artic Classes and Ice type related to each of them. Source: Transport Canada (2017)}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{example-image-b}
        \caption{Shipping Safety Control Zones.}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: a]

**UPDATE** after follow up question. (Using [former answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/682435/161015))

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftparskip}{1.5\baselineskip}

\usepackage{hyperref} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
}

\begin{document}        
    
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \centering
        \vspace{1cm}
        {\LARGE\noindent \textbf{TITLE OF MY WORK} \par}
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        %Thesis subtitle
        {\Large\noindent \par}
        \vspace{2cm}
        \vspace{1cm}
        {\Large
            by}
        
        \vspace{1cm}
        
        {\LARGE\noindent  MY NAME \par} 
        \vspace{1cm}
        {\Large \noindent Submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of Master of Applied Science \par
            \vspace{1cm}   
            April 2023} 
        \vfill  
        \hrule
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        
        {\Large\noindent \textcopyright\ Copyright by .....} 
    \end{titlepage}
    \cleardoublepage
    
    \pagenumbering{Roman} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
    \tableofcontents
    \cleardoublepage    

    \phantomsection % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
    \listoffigures  
    \cleardoublepage        

    \pagenumbering{arabic} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \chapter{One}
    
    Some text.
    
    \begin{figure}  
        \includegraphics{example-image-a}
        \caption{Artic Shipping Routes.}
    \end{figure}
    
        \begin{figure}  
        \includegraphics{example-image-a}
        \caption{Unique ships entering the Polar Code area 2013 and 2019. Source: adapted from PAME (2020)}
    \end{figure}
    
    \chapter{Two}
    
    Some more text.
    
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics{example-image-b}
            \caption{Sea Ice Extent.}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{example-image-b}
        \caption{Canadian Artic Classes and Ice type related to each of them. Source: Transport Canada (2017)}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{example-image-b}
        \caption{Shipping Safety Control Zones.}
    \end{figure}

\chapter{Three}

Some text.

\begin{figure}  
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Artic Shipping Routes.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}  
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Unique ships entering the Polar Code area 2013 and 2019. Source: adapted from PAME (2020)}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Four}

Some more text.

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    \caption{Sea Ice Extent.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    \caption{Canadian Artic Classes and Ice type related to each of them. Source: Transport Canada (2017)}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    \caption{Shipping Safety Control Zones.}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, however, the list of figure, when I click on the pdf, it leads to the cover page (???). I am using pagenumbering ROMAN for the preliminary pages. And also, the chapter title is too low on the page... how to place it higher?

Comment: @Ana Laura Bianco Please see the updated answer and my answer to your previous question. This site works better with one question at the time. Please add another question to format the chapter title.